# Solution for syncing the current project data across Eclipse plugin views?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I am making a set of Eclipse Plugins.
Each of these plugins display some data with respect to a project in the Eclipse Workspace.

What is the best practice/solution for loading data with respect to a unique project in each of these views?

I have the following options with me

1.)I provide a dropdown in each of the views and when the user changes dropdown the view gets refreshed with the respective project data.

2.)I give the User a "Load All Views" button when he right clicks in the package explorer and when he clicks this all views get loaded with the respective project data from package explorer

3.)Is there some other standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1.) seems to be the cleaner and unambiguous way to go.

Communication across views can be done using the selection service
[Selection Service](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html)